# setCurrentTab of a tabHost

Tags: android, static, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I'm asking if we can call a setCurrentTab on a tabhost from another class than the class that contains the tabhost and tabspecs?

Can we put

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
```

in another class than this one :

```
public class Main extends TabActivity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v("", "Welcome in Main");
    setContentView(R.layout.tab);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);  // Le TabHost a des Tabs

    TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");  // TabSpec: new tab - TabSpec : setContent to the tab
    firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Informations", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.database)).setContent(new Intent(this,FirstTab.class));
    tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);

    TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
    secondTabSpec.setIndicator("Graphiques", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chart)).setContent(new Intent(this,SecondTab.class));
    tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);

    TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");  // tid1 is firstTabSpec Id (used to access outside)
    thirdTabSpec.setIndicator("Réglages", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.settings)).setContent(new Intent(this,ThirdTab.class));
    tabHost.addTab(thirdTabSpec);
}

}
```

Can we make it a static var? how Can we achieve this?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Write more about what you want to achieve because it looks like you are thinking about really bad programming... You may cause memory leaks when using static variables that contain a reference to Context (such as TabHost). Why do you want to change current tab from other classes and what classes will be doing that?

Comment: I have a button in the first view, and if we push it, I want to see the second view (each view is on their own tab).. as if we push the tab ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You sure can. For your situation, a singleton of the TabActivity may work best. For example:

```
public class Main extends TabActivity{
    private staic Main theInstance;

    public static getInstance() {
        return Main.theInstance;
    }

    public Main() {
        Main.theInstance = this;
    }

    // The rest of your code here.
}
```

Then, from another class, you can just call:

Main.getInstance().getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);

NOTE: What I have provided is not a complete singleton implementation, but it should suffice for what you're doing. Depending on the class you're setting the tab from, you may want to check that `Main.getInstance()` is not null before calling the `setCurrentTab()` method.

Comment: It is not Main.getInstance().tabHost.setCurrentTab(1); ??? Or instread of the "this", I have to return the TabHost??

Comment: @clement, good catch, it would be `Main.getInstance().getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);`

Comment: I have to implement a getTabHost, but I cannot return a tabHost... How I declare it? as a public static too?

Comment: OK, I've put the TabHost as a private before the onCreate, and the method return simply the tabHost...

Answer (score 3):

But if you are in another activity, you won't see the tabs anyway will you?

I had a similar problem with a ListView which started the tabHost activity onItemClick to get that working, i passed the tabNumber i wanted to display, through the intent, then used setCurrentTab to set the current tab to the passed tab number. Not sure if this would work for you though.

EDIT: Here is how i did it:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, TabHostActivity.class);
i.putExtra("TabNumber", tabNumberToBeSelected); //tabNumberToBeSelected is an int
startActivity(i);
```

and then in the tabHost activity:

```
int tabNumber = getIntent().getIntExtra("TabNumber", 0);

//tabHost code goes here

tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabNumber);
```

Comment: I want see the tabs when I push the button! How can you pass the tabNumber trough intent? the intent is like that : new Intent(this,ThirdTab.class)

Answer (score 3):

In your activities FirstTab, SecondTab and ThirdTab you should use the method like:

```
boolean setCurrentTab(int i) {
    if (getParent() instanceof Main) {
        ((Main) getParent()).getTabHost().setCurrentTab(i);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As a result you can execute setCurrentTab from activities that are inside your tabs.