# Keeping tabhost while switching intent from button click

Tags: android, button, android-tabhost

I am adding a new tab layout to my app. My app has 4 activities.

Before, the navigation was done with buttons displayed in activities, for example a button in activity 1 make you go to section 4. Each button was starting a new activity with a new intent. To go back user could hit his native device back button.

Example of button:

```
Button b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTab4.class);
            startActivity(i);                           
        }
   });
```

Now, with the tabhost, user goes straight to desire activity, each activity is a child of my tabhost. However, I still need in my layout to keep some buttons that jump directly to a particular activity.

The problem, with these buttons, is that when they start a new activity, the tabhost disappears. I need to keep it at all time.

So how can I use the tabhost normally, but on the top of it also use custom buttons inside the layout of my sections that would keep the tabhost when I hit them?

My tabhost structure is very basic:

```
public class TabWidget extends TabActivity {    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.global_tabs);
    setTabs() ;     
    }   

private void setTabs() {        
    addTab("Act1", R.drawable.tab1, ActivityTab1.class);
    addTab("Act2", R.drawable.tab2, ActivityTab2.class);        
    addTab("Act3", R.drawable.tab1, ActivityTab3.class);
    addTab("Act4", R.drawable.tab2, ActivityTab4.class);
    }

private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c) {

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

    // SET TITLETAB
    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.titleTab);
    title.setText(labelId);

    // SET IMAGETAB
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }}
```

Thanks for your help

EDIT: I would rather avoid fragments because it's going to take me a lot of time to implement them and on the top of that to make it compatible with API<11

Answer (score 1):

All right, I've found it, thanks to this answer: [setCurrentTab of a tabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425742/setcurrenttab-of-a-tabhost)

BAsically in the main tabhost activity, add this

```
private static Main theInstance;

public static Main getInstance() {
    return Main.theInstance;
}

public Main () {
    Main.theInstance = this;
}
```

In the child, you can have a button sending the user to any tab + corresponding activity:

```
Button b1_3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_3);
    b1_3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TabWidget.getInstance().getTabHost().setCurrentTab(3);
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you use tabhost and activities instead of Fragments? I think you would find Fragments more suited to what you're trying to do.

As for your question - you can switch the displayed tab with

```
 void   setCurrentTab(int index) 
 void   setCurrentTabByTag(String tag)
```

so there's no need to manually starting an activity on button press, just switch the displayed tab using these methods.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I use this code in my child activity, how can I "call" the tabHost functions?

Comment: I've seen it done by invoking the tabHost activity from the child activity and putting a key in the intent that defined which tab should be shown. So the parent activity would check for the intent key whenever it is created, and depending on it would invoke the method on tabhost.

Comment: Ok, I agree with this theory, but how can I use setCurrentTab(int index) pratically in a child activity?