# Activity in TabActivity doesn't run onCreate Method when clicked second time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I have a `TabActivity` which includes 3 `tabs`. And I set `currentActivity` as `1` not the default one, `0` . When I start my `TabActivity` I figured out that Activity0 also runs but Tabactivity shows the interface of Activity1 which I set as `currentActivity`. Furthermore when I click tab2 (include Activity2) and click again tba1 or tab0, they dont run again. As I think TabActivity just let to run one time. I would like to restart each activiy in tab whenever I click tabs. And I would like to keep these in trace so that when clicking back button it should be tracable.

```
public class ActivityInTab extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener{
TabHost tabHost;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityintab);

    tabHost = getTabHost();

    TabSpec meSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Ben");
    meSpec.setIndicator("Ben", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_me));
    Intent meIntent = new Intent(this, MeActivity.class);
    meSpec.setContent(meIntent);

    TabSpec searchSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Arama");
    searchSpec.setIndicator("Çevrende Ara", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_search));
//        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
//        searchSpec.setContent(searchIntent);

    TabSpec resultSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Aradıklarım");
    resultSpec.setIndicator("Arama  Sonuçlarım", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_result));
//        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
//        resultSpec.setContent(resultIntent);       

    tabHost.addTab(searchSpec); 
    tabHost.addTab(meSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(resultSpec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    if(tabId.equals("Ben") && tabHost.getCurrentTab()==0){
        MeActivity meact = (MeActivity) getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(tabId);

    }

    if(tabId.equals("Arama") && tabHost.getCurrentTab()==1){
        SearchActivity sact= (SearchActivity) getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(tabId); 
    }
    if(tabId.equals("Aradıklarım") && tabHost.getCurrentTab()==2){
        ResultActivity ract = (ResultActivity) getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(tabId);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: onCreate will be called only once. You can check for onResume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set  flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` for your tab intents.

```
Intent meIntent = new Intent(this, MeActivity.class);
meIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

And also for the commented tabs like this

```
Intent searchIntent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
 searchIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: Thank you. This problem is solved. As you see from my code I set current activity 1. However activity 0 which is SearchActivity also run first time when I call TabActivity. Is there any way to prevent this without setting tabHost.setCurrentTab(0)?

Comment: @Emilla check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425742/setcurrenttab-of-a-tabhost

Comment: @Emilla You mark this as answer by clicking the right mark beside the answer